# Configuring the redirects for an application registration in Azure Active Directory network error

Tags: azure-active-directory

When I try to configure authentication of a registered web .Net Core app in Azure Active Directory by updating the redirect URLs I get a network error:
"Configuring your application registration
Network error: There is an issue establishing a connection to the service. Please refresh the browser to try again"
If I look into console I see CORS error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications/09bfef71-7a2b-4560-b2a2-947a4a16de0f' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response."

See also attached image:
[image: Network error]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check if you have any CORS extension installed on your browser. That was the case for me. I had [this extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) installed but once disabled I was able to save the changes